# Add post title as alt tag for featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails, array

How do I add post title as alt tag in a post? I tried using array(title => `'.the_title.')` but it didnt work. I think I am not suppose to use `the_title`. I tired using `get_the_title` as well.

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you need an `alt` _attribute?_ Note, there is no `alt` tag.

Answer (score 1):

@its_me got it almost right. Those args must be 2nd resp. 3rd Parameter, not first:

```
$attr = array(
    'title' => 'howdy partner',
    'alt'   => 'a nice view of the ocean',
);

// pick one, note 2 or 3 arguments:
the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', $attr );

echo("<a href='$p->permalink'>". // null for current $post->ID (use within loop)
    get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'post-thumbnail', $attr ).
    "</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `<?php the_title(); ?>`

Here is example -

`<img src="http://link-to-image" title="Image title" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>`

Comment: rather use `the_title_attribute()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute

Answer (score 0):

What code does your theme use to show the featured image (aka post-thumbnail)? Most themes do it like this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

or like this (**the right way to do it**):

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
?>
```

In that case, replace the code with this:

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail(
            array(
                'alt' => trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) ),
            );
        );
    } 
?>
```

...where, `'alt' => trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) )` tells the `the_post_thumbnail` function that it should use the post's title instead of image's alt text.

**READ:** [WordPress Codex — Function Reference for `the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)